# localToGlobal/globalToLocal AS3 confusion

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates

I want to move a display object from one container to another, but have it appear in the same place on screen.

I thought I'd understood this years ago, but the following does not work:

```
function moveToNewContainer(obj:DisplayObject, newParent:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    var pos:Point = new Point(obj.x, obj.y);
    var currentParent:DisplayObjectContainer = obj.parent;
    pos = currentParent.localToGlobal(pos);
    currentParent.removeChild(obj);
    newParent.addChild(obj);
    pos = newParent.globalToLocal(pos);
    obj.x = pos.x;
    obj.y = pos.y;
}
```

This doesn't position the object in the same place as I would have expected.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, please?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 7):

Using `localToGlobal`/`globalToLocal` and setting the `x` and `y` properties like you showed calculates the correct *position* for the object in its new parent, but does not adjust for other aspects of the transformation such as scaling or rotation. In other words, the object's registration point will indeed remain in the same place, but the object may be rotated, scaled, or sheared differently.

The solution to your problem will need to take into account the `transform.concatenatedMatrix` properties of the old and new parents--you'll need to multiply the object's transformation matrix by one and then by the inverse of the other, or something along those lines. Leave a comment if you need help working out the math.

Comment: Thanks to you and Adam Smith for your replies. As far as I can tell there are no scaling, rotation or shearing transforms to the parents. I've fixed the problem for now by just setting the position of both parents to 0,0 - there is obviously something else going on. But your answers are certainly both valid.

Comment: You may have realized this already, but you also need to make sure that none of the old or new parents' *ancestors* have any scaling, rotation, or shearing, all the way up to the root (or at least up to the first common ancestor).

Comment: I have checked and there is no transformation of that type on any of the parents going up to the root. But, you are right to check and your advice still holds.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, provided that both containers have no transformations applied. If your clips are scaled, rotated, etc.. you need to handle that in addition to the coordinate space transformations that localToGlobal and globalToLocal do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your containers are actually placed on stage. If your new container isn't added as a child to stage, function globalToLocal fails, just because it doesnt know how to correctly calculate that data.